# Define a custom kill signal for PHP process

Tags: php, posix

I am working on a long-running PHP script. The script runs from command line. I need to add a graceful shutdown capability. I tried to use the process control library to handle POSIX signals. Unfortunately, some third party libraries that I am using are also intercepting POSIX signals, and they handle the signal and my script is not informed. I tried using SIGTERM first. Then I tried using custom signals SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2, same happened.

Is it possible to define/use a new signal that is not defined in POSIX?

If not, what else can I use to implement graceful shutdown?

Comment: How do you know the signals are swallowed by the third-party libraries?

Comment: I see it in the logs, that library is stoping its operation on receiving signal and app is terminated.